# Add BCC to mail via VBS (through GPO)

Tags: outlook, vbscript, bcc

Every mail sent should BCC to a second E-Mail address.

I found VBA code examples like:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                             Cancel As Boolean)
Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim strMsg As String
Dim res As Integer
Dim strBcc As String
On Error Resume Next

' #### USER OPTIONS ####
' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable
' to a name in the address book
strBcc = "someone@somewhere.dom"

Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
objRecip.Type = olBCC
If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
    strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
             "Do you want still to send the message?"
    res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
    If res = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If

Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub
```

That works **if** I add the code to Outlook.

Since I want to use it in an Active Directory-Environment I would like to do it via GPO settings.
I installed the Office 2016 ADML/ADMX Template files but found no option to configure an automatic bcc for every mail sent.

I found [Active Directory Outlook Signature – VBScript](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/active-directory-outlook-signature-vbs-script/) to set a E-Mail Signature and thought this might do the trick.

Is it possible (I'm no VBS expert) to write a script that runs on user logon that adds a bcc to every mail sent?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that via GPO - there is no out if the box feature in Outlook which would auto BCC. It has to be done in code - script or a COM addin.

Comment: Can you helpe me on that script or COM addin?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, but there are dozens versions of this question already asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=auto+bcc

Comment: I know that. The basic code is already written, but it can only be executed when you open outlook and hit Alt+F11. I would like to run it via a script that gets executed on user logon so I can set it via GPO's. I'm just asking for a starting point or some advice to get started with the script.

Comment: If macros are enabled, you script should run on startup. Otherwise you can create a COM addin and install it once on logon - start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019